# How should characters be escaped in github markdown code blocks

Tags: github, markdown

It appears that a github fenced code block doesn't accept arbitrary character strings. A block like this:

````
```haskell
sinusoid1 = plot_lines_values .~ [[ (x,(am x)) | x <- [0,(0.5)..400]]]
          $ plot_lines_style  . line_color .~ opaque blue
          $ plot_lines_title .~ "am"
          $ def
```
````

ends displaying the code truncated a the first < symbol.

A real example of this is here:

https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki/example-1

Do I need to escape certain character strings in github markdown code blocks? How do I do this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in their parsing code as no character should be interpreted within code blocks. Just to be sure, did you try giving your file a ".md" extension?

Comment: This is using githubs wiki - I dont choose the file extension.

Comment: Looks like your solution was to use HTML/XML entities. E.g., &lt;

Answer (score 2):

If you use a backslash before the markdown HTML < tag, the parser will treat it as a literal.

So to show this:

```
@interface ViewController ()<MPC_MaxCharacterDelimitedTextFieldDelegate>
```

Escape the < tag with a backslash:

```
@interface ViewController ()\<MPC_MaxCharacterDelimitedTextFieldDelegate>
```